# Help with interpreting an interpolation problem

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis, interpolation

I don't know if this is the appropriate place to ask this, but I really do need some help. I am doing a homework problem and I don't understand what is being asked. It goes as follows:

> Write a MATLAB function to evaluate the trigonometric interpolant $p_n(x)$ for a given set of samples, $\bf{y}$:

Here it follows with some comments about making such a function, I'll leave that out since it's not relevant, but it goes on to say:

> To test your program use $f(x) = 10cos(x)+5cos(3x)$ and plot the maximum error $max |p_n(x)-f(x)|$ for $n= 4,8,16,32,64.$ Verify that the maximum error is close to machine precision for $n=32,64.$ What is the reason behind this?

So I was able to find the interpolating function $p_n(x)$, but I don't know what the next part is asking. Am I supposed to find the maximum value of $g_n(x) = |p_n(x)-f(x)|$ for each $n$, say it is $g_n(x_0)$, then plot $g_i(x_0)$ vs $i$ for $i= 1...n$? So effectively, each value $g_i(x_0)$ is plotted on an $y$- axis and $i$ on a corresponding $x$-axis?  Or am I simply supposed to make a plot of $g_n(x) = |p_n(x)-f(x)|$ for each n?

Also, how do I know when I am close to machine precision? When I start getting cancellation errors?

Thank in advance for the help.

By the way, I am using Julia to do this, not MATLAB.

Comment: What is the trigonometric interpolant, is $p_n$ built with trigonometric functons?

Comment: $p_n$ is built using cosines and sines as a basis function. So basically a discrete Fourier transform is used. I don't know the exact interpolant  because the package I used to do FFT only gives node values. This is because they were already evaluated.

Comment: In Matlab you can assume "eps" to be machine precision I am sure Julia either has a similar command or mentions its in its documentation. You were asked to find the error of your interpolant. Since there is no guarantee that any given function can be written as the combination of complex exponentials, you may have some errors, but for your example function you are to get 0, however, your computer uses numerical methods and has a finite precision. So seeing your error on the order of the machine precision you may rest assured and say "Oh I did it correctly"

Comment: Essentially you are verifying the Nyquist version of the sampling theorem (which was one of the inspirations for Shannon's sampling theorem). Sampling a periodic function that is composed of the first $N$ harmonics requires at least $2N+1$ samples to get a useful reconstruction.

Comment: Where are the samples taken? Equidistant over $[0,2\pi]$?

Comment: Is this (a variation of) problem 4.22 from [*"Scientific Computing - An Introduction using Maple and MATLAB"*](https://books.google.de/books?id=QX7HBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA177) by Walter Gander, ‎Martin J. Gander, ‎Felix Kwok? By leaving out the 10th harmonic term the second part has become ambiguous as the interpolation here should reach that precision earlier.

Comment: If this is homework, surely the textbook mentions somewhere a usable formula for the trigonometric interpolant.

Comment: @LutzL just blew my mind, I didn’t know about those theorems.

Answer (score 0):

You are to interpolate $f$ by
$$
p_{n=2m}(x)=a_0+\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}(a_j\cos(jx)+b_j\sin(jx))+a_{m}\cos(mx)
$$
at samples $y_k=f(x_k)$, $x_k=k\frac{2\pi}n=k\frac{\pi}m$.

Regardless of how you solve the resulting linear system for the coefficients, for $$f(x)=10\cos(x)+5\cos(3x)$$ the solution is uniquely given by $a_1=10$, $a_3=5$, all other coefficients $0$ for $m\ge 3$, $n\ge 6$. All deviations from that result are due to floating point noise, and since the discrete Fourier transform is orthogonal, the relative size of the noise is bounded to essentially the machine constant. For the given sample sizes this should happen for $n=8,16,32,64$.

---

For the original task description from in [1], where
$$
f(x)=10\cos(x)-3\sin(3x)+5\cos(3x)-15\cos(10x)
$$
interpolation results in exact reconstruction of that formula for $m\ge 10$, $n\ge20$, so that indeed only in the cases $n=32,64$ one can expect the errors to be on the magnitude of $10\epsilon$.

- [1]: Walter Gander, ‎Martin J. Gander, ‎Felix Kwok [*"Scientific Computing - An Introduction using Maple and MATLAB"*](https://books.google.de/books?id=QX7HBAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA177), problem 4.22, page 177